# Using multiple IFs when validating a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my form validation I am try to check for empty strings, which will display one error message, then check that the length is no more than 15 character, which should display a different message.  The problem is, the way I have it written, it is only check the length.  If I remove it, the empty string check works.  It seems it is only check the last thing in my statement.  How can I rewrite thig to work for both items?

I tried both this:

```
const validate = (fieldValues = values) => {
    const temp = { ...errors };
    if ('name' in fieldValues)
        { temp.name = fieldValues.name ? '' : 'Location Name is required.'; }
        { temp.name = fieldValues.name.length < 16 ? '' : 'Location Name limited to 15 Characters.'; } 
    setErrors({
        ...temp
    });
    if (fieldValues === values)
        { return Object.values(temp).every(x => x === ''); }
};
```

And this:

```
const validate = (fieldValues = values) => {
    const temp = { ...errors };
    if ('name' in fieldValues)
        { temp.name = fieldValues.name ? '' : 'Location Name is required.'; }
    if ('name' in fieldValues)
        { temp.name = fieldValues.name.length < 16 ? '' : 'Location Name limited to 15 Characters.'; }
    setErrors({
        ...temp
    });
    if (fieldValues === values)
        { return Object.values(temp).every(x => x === ''); }
};
```

Both did the same thing.

adding pipes between just caused an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the if statements in the second snippet can be simplified a bit:

```
if ('name' in fieldValues) {
    temp.name = fieldValues.name ? '' : 'Location Name is required.';
    temp.name = fieldValues.name.length < 16 ? '' : 'Location Name limited to 15 Characters.';
}
```

Now let's step through that code, assuming `fieldValues.name` is an empty string:

1. `if ('name' in fieldValues)' {...`

`fieldValues.name` is an empty string, but is still present, so `'name' in fieldValues` is true. That means we'll execute the code in the if statement.

2. `temp.name = fieldValues.name ? '' : 'Location Name is required.';`

`fieldValues.name` is `''` (empty string), which evaluates to false in JavaScript. So now `temp.name` is `'Location Name is required.'`. Great!

3. `temp.name = fieldValues.name.length < 16 ? '' : 'Location Name limited to 15 Characters.';`

`fieldValues.name.length` is zero, which is less than 16. So now you **overwrite the previous error** and `temp.name` is now `''`.

A better implementation would look like:

```
if ('name' in fieldValues) {
  // Check fieldValues.name is null or empty
  if (!fieldValues.name) {
    temp.name = 'Location Name is required.';
  }
  // Check if length of string is too long
  else if(fieldValues.name.length > 15) {
    temp.name = 'Location Name limited to 15 Characters.';
  }
}
...
```

Comment: Great Explanation!  You really helped me understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a simple form validation function in JavaScript that checks for empty strings and strings with more than 15 characters:

This function assumes that there is an HTML input element with the id "myInput" and an HTML element with the id "error" to display the error messages.

The function first gets the input value and trims any whitespace from the beginning and end. If the input is empty, it sets the error message to "Please enter a value" and returns false, indicating that validation failed.

If the input is not empty, it checks if the length of the input is greater than 15. If it is, it sets the error message to "The input must be 15 characters or less" and returns false.

If validation is successful, the function clears the error message and returns true, indicating that validation passed.

```
function validateForm() {
  // get the input value from the HTML input element
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

  // get the HTML element to display error messages
  var errorElement = document.getElementById("error");

  // check if input is empty or only contains whitespace
  if (input.trim() === "") {
    // if input is empty, set error message and return false
    errorElement.innerHTML = "Please enter a value";
    return false;
  } else if (input.length > 15) {
    // if input is longer than 15 characters, set error message and return false
    errorElement.innerHTML = "The input must be 15 characters or less";
    return false;
  }

  // if validation is successful, clear the error message and return true
  errorElement.innerHTML = "";
  return true;
}
```

Comment: OP is using React so this answer will conflict with the way React reconciles DOM updates.

Comment: I really like the option to remove whitespace.  That has been a concern, but didn't know if there was a method to remove it.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using JavaScript to deal with the validation is to use the built-in browser form validation. Set the input as `required`, and then use input attributes like `pattern` to add input boundaries. Then have form notify the user when it's submitted if those boundaries are violated.

In this example the browser adds a pattern to the input to ensure that at least one character is entered, and less than fifteen are entered. Try clicking the button without entering anything in the input. A validation popup appears telling you to fill in the field. Adding more that fifteen characters will reveal a differently worded popup.

Aside: you could also add `maxlength` and `size` to inhibit the visual boundaries of the input field, and ARIA descriptions to make the form more accessible.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ input, setInput ] = useState('');

  function handleChange(e) {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(`State: ${input}`);
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label for="text">Enter text</label>
        <input
          required
          id="text"
          type="text"
          aria-describedby="textHint"
          placeholder="1-15 characters"
          // maxlength="15"
          // size="15"
          pattern="^.{1,15}$"
          value={input}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <span class="hint" id="textHint">
          Enter text between 1 and 15 characters in length.
        </span>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </section>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
* { font-size: 1.1rem; }
input { margin: 0 0.25rem; }
input:valid { border: 1px solid green; outline: none;}
input:invalid { border: 1px solid red; outline: none; }
.hint { margin-top: 0.25rem; font-size: 0.9rem; display: block; color: darkblue; }
button { margin-top: 0.25rem; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I really like this.  Will have to look into how to implement it on a form with more than a single field.  I only posted the question about the field I was wanting to add 2 stipulations to.

Answer (score 0):

react version

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Form() {
  // set initial state for the input and error message
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  // handle input change
  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  }

  // handle form submission
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // validate input
    if (input.trim() === "") {
      setErrorMessage("Please enter a value");
    } else if (input.length > 15) {
      setErrorMessage("The input must be 15 characters or less");
    } else {
      setErrorMessage("");
      // do something with the validated input
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Input:
        <input type="text" value={input} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      {errorMessage && <p>{errorMessage}</p>}
    </form>
  );
}
```

In this example, we define a Form component that contains a form with an input field, a submit button, and an error message that will be displayed if the input is invalid.

We use the useState hook to manage the input state and error message state. When the user types in the input field, the handleInputChange function is called and updates the input state with the new value.

When the user submits the form, the handleSubmit function is called. This function first prevents the default form submission behavior. Then it checks if the input is empty or longer than 15 characters and sets the error message accordingly. If the input is valid, it clears the error message and does something with the validated input (which you can define yourself, depending on your use case).

Finally, we render the form with the input field, submit button, and error message. The errorMessage variable is only displayed if it is truthy (i.e., not an empty string or null).